# Particle System Removes Landscape when it is rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, error, particle-nodes

Simply put, I am trying to create a Mars scene but when I go to render an image, the landscape disappears.

I am using Blender version 2.92.

I am using two particle systems to spread rocks of various sizes over a generated landscape, one of them is flat rocks, and the other is pebbles. From the viewport, it looks alright and wanted to see what it looked like when I rendered, but when I go to render the image, it completely removes the landscape from the render and only shows the rocks (particles).

Here is the Viewport, which shows the entire scene as intended:
[image]

Here is the Rendered Image, the one that lacks the landscape.
[image]

The rocks were created using the Rock Generator, and the Landscape was created using A.N.T Landscapes, both are from add-ons. Materials on the objects are PBR materials gathered from various sources.

Does anyone have an idea of what is causing this error? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Duplicate your landscape before applying the particle system and then apply particles to the duplicate.

Comment: That's a great idea. I will try that out when I get back to it later. I will also check for that Render icon within the Outliner. Thank you for the suggestions and the quick answer, I will try it out later!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that *Show Emitter* is enabled in the *Render* settings for your particle systems.

[image]

Comment: That did the trick. One of them was turned off. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Outliner and click on the Filter settings. Make sure the Render icon is highlighted (camera icon) that will let you see if anything is hidden in render. If you see next to your landscape that there is an X on the camera (render) icon, then you know it's been hidden in render. [image]